# Getting class constant inside class

Tags: php

What's the difference between `self::CONSTANT_NAME` and `static::CONSTANT_NAME`?

Is calling constant via `static::` only 5.3 feature?

Comment: This is related to late static binding. But, is it even possible to override class constants? If not, I believe it'd be irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is pretty much what [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) are all about.

Short explanation:

`self::` will refer to the class type *inside which the code using self:: is written*.

`static::` will refer to the class type *of the actual object that on which the code using static:: is being executed*.

This means that there's only a difference if we are talking about classes in the same inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

When you use static::NAME it's a feature called late static binding (or LSB). More information about this feature is at the php.net documentation page of LSB: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

An example is this use case:

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        self::who();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
?>
```

This outputs A, which is not always desirable. Now replacing `self` with `static` creates this:

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
?>
```

And, as you might expect, it ouputs "B"